# How to observe last emitted WorkManager getWorkInfoByIdLiveData with Android Worker

Tags: android, android-livedata, android-workmanager

My current Android application employs

```
archWorkerRuntimeVersion = '2.3.0-beta02'

api "androidx.work:work-runtime:$archWorkerRuntimeVersion"
api "androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:$archWorkerRuntimeVersion"
```

I am observing the worker state via LiveData as follows:-

```
 WorkManager.getInstance(applicationContext).getWorkInfoByIdLiveData(experimentRequest.id).observe(lifeCycleOwner, observer)
```

where lifeCycleOwner is my Activity and observer is a static val

```
private val observer = object : Observer<WorkInfo> {
    override fun onChanged(it: WorkInfo?) {
        Log.e("Worker", "this is our single observer $it $this")
        if (it == null) return
        repository.storeCurrentWorkId(it.id)
    }
}
```

the comment for `observe(lifeCycleOwner, observer)` states:-

```
/**
 * Adds the given observer to the observers list within the lifespan of the given
 * owner. The events are dispatched on the main thread. If LiveData already has data
 * set, it will be delivered to the observer.
 * <p>
 * The observer will only receive events if the owner is in {@link Lifecycle.State#STARTED}
 * or {@link Lifecycle.State#RESUMED} state (active).
 * <p>
 * If the owner moves to the {@link Lifecycle.State#DESTROYED} state, the observer will
 * automatically be removed.
 * <p>
 * When data changes while the {@code owner} is not active, it will not receive any updates.
 * If it becomes active again, it will receive the last available data automatically.
 * <p>
 * LiveData keeps a strong reference to the observer and the owner as long as the
 * given LifecycleOwner is not destroyed. When it is destroyed, LiveData removes references to
 * the observer &amp; the owner.
 * <p>
 * If the given owner is already in {@link Lifecycle.State#DESTROYED} state, LiveData
 * ignores the call.
 * <p>
 * If the given owner, observer tuple is already in the list, the call is ignored.
 * If the observer is already in the list with another owner, LiveData throws an
 * {@link IllegalArgumentException}.
 *
 * @param owner    The LifecycleOwner which controls the observer
 * @param observer The observer that will receive the events
 */
```

this statement does not appear to hold true though

```
If it becomes active again, it will receive the last available data automatically.
```

Unless I am misinterpreting it's meaning.

I took this to mean that when my activity become active again I would receive the latest (last) available data.

from my testing this is not the case, the only data I receive is any new data that is sent AFTER my activity becomes active again.

What am I doing wrong?

Is there any way to receive the latest data when my activity becomes active?

UPDATE

I have created the following simple Android App to showcase this issue.

This Android App consists of three Activities.

```
Dummy Main Activity
Worker Activity
Dummy Second Activity
```

My tests involve

```
1). Starting App with Dummy Main Activity, navigating to WorkerActivity, starting Worker and waiting for the worker to SUCCEED

2). Starting App with Dummy Main Activity, navigating to WorkerActivity, starting Worker, then navigate to Dummy Second Activity and returning to WorkerActivity

3). Starting App with Dummy Main Activity, navigating to WorkerActivity, starting Worker, then return to Dummy Main Activity and returning to WorkerActivity
```

The worker Activity starts and observers the LiveData as shown below

```
class WorkerActivity : AppCompatActivity(), Observer<WorkInfo?> {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ninth)

        findViewById<Button>(R.id.start_work_tags_button).setOnClickListener {
            doSomeWork()
        }

        findViewById<Button>(R.id.start_work_button).setOnClickListener {
            startActivity(Intent(this@WorkerActivity, Seventh::class.java))
        }

    }

    private fun doSomeWork() {
        val ninthRequest: OneTimeWorkRequest = manufactureOneTimeWorkRequest(NinthWorker::class.java)

        WorkManager.getInstance(applicationContext)
            .beginUniqueWork(UNIQUE_WORK_NAME, ExistingWorkPolicy.KEEP, ninthRequest)
            .enqueue()

        val workInfos = WorkManager.getInstance(applicationContext).getWorkInfoByIdLiveData(ninthRequest.id)
        workInfos.observe(this as LifecycleOwner, this as Observer<in WorkInfo>)
    }

    private fun manufactureOneTimeWorkRequest(klazz: Class<out CoroutineWorker>): OneTimeWorkRequest {
        return OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(klazz).addTag(WORK_IN_PROGRESS_TAG + "${UUID.randomUUID()}").build()
    }

    companion object {
        private const val WORK_IN_PROGRESS_TAG = "SYNC-IN-PROGRESS-TAG"
        private const val UNIQUE_WORK_NAME = "SYNC-UNIQUE_WORK_NAME"
    }

    override fun onChanged(workInfo: WorkInfo?) {
        Log.e("NINTH", "onChanged($workInfo)")

    }
}
```

The two "Dummy" activities are employed to enable the `WorkerActivity` as LifeCycle owner to become "in active"

The logs I see for test 1). are shown here:-

```
2020-01-14 10:54:36.114 23452-23452/org.vulgaris.behave E/APPLICATION: onActivityCreated() org.vulgaris.behave.sixth.DummyMainActivity@cdc2743
2020-01-14 10:54:36.228 23452-23452/org.vulgaris.behave E/APPLICATION: onActivityStarted() org.vulgaris.behave.sixth.DummyMainActivity@cdc2743
2020-01-14 10:54:36.230 23452-23452/org.vulgaris.behave E/APPLICATION: onActivityResumed() org.vulgaris.behave.sixth.DummyMainActivity@cdc2743
2020-01-14 10:54:43.324 23452-23452/org.vulgaris.behave E/APPLICATION: onActivityPaused() org.vulgaris.behave.sixth.DummyMainActivity@cdc2743
2020-01-14 10:54:43.343 23452-23452/org.vulgaris.behave E/APPLICATION: onActivityCreated() org.vulgaris.behave.ninth.WorkerActivity@abd837d
2020-01-14 10:54:43.386 23452-23452/org.vulgaris.behave E/APPLICATION: onActivityStarted() org.vulgaris.behave.ninth.WorkerActivity@abd837d
2020-01-14 10:54:43.387 23452-23452/org.vulgaris.behave E/APPLICATION: onActivityResumed() org.vulgaris.behave.ninth.WorkerActivity@abd837d
2020-01-14 10:54:43.776 23452-23452/org.vulgaris.behave E/APPLICATION: onActivityStopped() org.vulgaris.behave.sixth.DummyMainActivity@cdc2743
2020-01-14 10:54:43.778 23452-23452/org.vulgaris.behave E/APPLICATION: onActivitySaveInstanceState() org.vulgaris.behave.sixth.DummyMainActivity@cdc2743
2020-01-14 10:54:48.812 23452-23452/org.vulgaris.behave E/WorkerActivity: onChanged(WorkInfo{mId='f3655bdd-3b1d-4e59-a896-3798ec860856', mState=ENQUEUED, mOutputData=Data {}, mTags=[org.vulgaris.behave.worker.NinthWorker, SYNC-IN-PROGRESS-TAG691b47cb-143f-42fc-8d88-903880e1f699], mProgress=Data {}})
2020-01-14 10:54:48.826 23452-23584/org.vulgaris.behave E/NinthWorker:  doWork 56fd9de0-ad8e-4275-b8a0-28e0cd045b9c  inputData = Data {}
2020-01-14 10:54:48.829 23452-23452/org.vulgaris.behave E/WorkerActivity: onChanged(WorkInfo{mId='f3655bdd-3b1d-4e59-a896-3798ec860856', mState=RUNNING, mOutputData=Data {}, mTags=[org.vulgaris.behave.worker.NinthWorker, SYNC-IN-PROGRESS-TAG691b47cb-143f-42fc-8d88-903880e1f699], mProgress=Data {}})
2020-01-14 10:55:48.851 23452-23583/org.vulgaris.behave I/WM-WorkerWrapper: Worker result SUCCESS for Work [ id=f3655bdd-3b1d-4e59-a896-3798ec860856, tags={ org.vulgaris.behave.worker.NinthWorker, SYNC-IN-PROGRESS-TAG691b47cb-143f-42fc-8d88-903880e1f699 } ]
2020-01-14 10:55:48.902 23452-23452/org.vulgaris.behave E/WorkerActivity: onChanged(WorkInfo{mId='f3655bdd-3b1d-4e59-a896-3798ec860856', mState=SUCCEEDED, mOutputData=Data {}, mTags=[org.vulgaris.behave.worker.NinthWorker, SYNC-IN-PROGRESS-TAG691b47cb-143f-42fc-8d88-903880e1f699], mProgress=Data {}})
```

The logs I see for test 2). are shown here:-

```
2020-01-14 10:59:20.726 23452-23452/org.vulgaris.behave E/APPLICATION: onActivityCreated() org.vulgaris.behave.sixth.DummyMainActivity@6a03dee
2020-01-14 10:59:20.780 23452-23452/org.vulgaris.behave E/APPLICATION: onActivityStarted() org.vulgaris.behave.sixth.DummyMainActivity@6a03dee
2020-01-14 10:59:20.781 23452-23452/org.vulgaris.behave E/APPLICATION: onActivityResumed() org.vulgaris.behave.sixth.DummyMainActivity@6a03dee
2020-01-14 10:59:23.781 23452-23452/org.vulgaris.behave E/APPLICATION: onActivityPaused() org.vulgaris.behave.sixth.DummyMainActivity@6a03dee
2020-01-14 10:59:23.799 23452-23452/org.vulgaris.behave E/APPLICATION: onActivityCreated() org.vulgaris.behave.ninth.WorkerActivity@2fe5636
2020-01-14 10:59:23.836 23452-23452/org.vulgaris.behave E/APPLICATION: onActivityStarted() org.vulgaris.behave.ninth.WorkerActivity@2fe5636
2020-01-14 10:59:23.837 23452-23452/org.vulgaris.behave E/APPLICATION: onActivityResumed() org.vulgaris.behave.ninth.WorkerActivity@2fe5636
2020-01-14 10:59:24.209 23452-23452/org.vulgaris.behave E/APPLICATION: onActivityStopped() org.vulgaris.behave.sixth.DummyMainActivity@6a03dee
2020-01-14 10:59:24.210 23452-23452/org.vulgaris.behave E/APPLICATION: onActivitySaveInstanceState() org.vulgaris.behave.sixth.DummyMainActivity@6a03dee
2020-01-14 10:59:30.564 23452-23452/org.vulgaris.behave E/WorkerActivity: onChanged(WorkInfo{mId='da800c85-485d-4cb5-9931-d3f20edf611e', mState=ENQUEUED, mOutputData=Data {}, mTags=[SYNC-IN-PROGRESS-TAG6c6ff5e2-b8a7-4f73-99e6-c112f7598287, org.vulgaris.behave.worker.NinthWorker], mProgress=Data {}})
2020-01-14 10:59:30.585 23452-23452/org.vulgaris.behave E/WorkerActivity: onChanged(WorkInfo{mId='da800c85-485d-4cb5-9931-d3f20edf611e', mState=RUNNING, mOutputData=Data {}, mTags=[SYNC-IN-PROGRESS-TAG6c6ff5e2-b8a7-4f73-99e6-c112f7598287, org.vulgaris.behave.worker.NinthWorker], mProgress=Data {}})
2020-01-14 10:59:30.585 23452-23585/org.vulgaris.behave E/NinthWorker:  doWork 6407357d-0471-41ee-8ea2-6cedeaf1e463  inputData = Data {}
2020-01-14 10:59:31.749 23452-23452/org.vulgaris.behave E/APPLICATION: onActivityPaused() org.vulgaris.behave.ninth.WorkerActivity@2fe5636
2020-01-14 10:59:31.767 23452-23452/org.vulgaris.behave E/APPLICATION: onActivityCreated() org.vulgaris.behave.seventh.DummySecondActivity@3572f3a
2020-01-14 10:59:31.834 23452-23452/org.vulgaris.behave E/APPLICATION: onActivityStarted() org.vulgaris.behave.seventh.DummySecondActivity@3572f3a
2020-01-14 10:59:31.835 23452-23452/org.vulgaris.behave E/APPLICATION: onActivityResumed() org.vulgaris.behave.seventh.DummySecondActivity@3572f3a
2020-01-14 10:59:32.211 23452-23452/org.vulgaris.behave E/APPLICATION: onActivityStopped() org.vulgaris.behave.ninth.WorkerActivity@2fe5636
2020-01-14 10:59:32.211 23452-23452/org.vulgaris.behave E/APPLICATION: onActivitySaveInstanceState() org.vulgaris.behave.ninth.WorkerActivity@2fe5636
2020-01-14 10:59:33.112 23452-23452/org.vulgaris.behave E/APPLICATION: onActivityPaused() org.vulgaris.behave.seventh.DummySecondActivity@3572f3a
2020-01-14 10:59:33.128 23452-23452/org.vulgaris.behave E/APPLICATION: onActivityStarted() org.vulgaris.behave.ninth.WorkerActivity@2fe5636
2020-01-14 10:59:33.129 23452-23452/org.vulgaris.behave E/APPLICATION: onActivityResumed() org.vulgaris.behave.ninth.WorkerActivity@2fe5636

I SHOULD SEE "WorkerActivity: onChanged(WorkInfo{mId='da800c85-485d-4cb5-9931-d3f20edf611e', mState=RUNNING, mOutputData=Data {}, mTags=[SYNC-IN-PROGRESS-TAG6c6ff5e2-b8a7-4f73-99e6-c112f7598287, org.vulgaris.behave.worker.NinthWorker], mProgress=Data {}})" HERE

2020-01-14 10:59:33.510 23452-23452/org.vulgaris.behave E/APPLICATION: onActivityStopped() org.vulgaris.behave.seventh.DummySecondActivity@3572f3a
2020-01-14 10:59:33.512 23452-23452/org.vulgaris.behave E/APPLICATION: onActivityDestroyed() org.vulgaris.behave.seventh.DummySecondActivity@3572f3a
2020-01-14 11:00:30.624 23452-23583/org.vulgaris.behave I/WM-WorkerWrapper: Worker result SUCCESS for Work [ id=da800c85-485d-4cb5-9931-d3f20edf611e, tags={ SYNC-IN-PROGRESS-TAG6c6ff5e2-b8a7-4f73-99e6-c112f7598287, org.vulgaris.behave.worker.NinthWorker } ]
2020-01-14 11:00:30.673 23452-23452/org.vulgaris.behave E/WorkerActivity: onChanged(WorkInfo{mId='da800c85-485d-4cb5-9931-d3f20edf611e', mState=SUCCEEDED, mOutputData=Data {}, mTags=[SYNC-IN-PROGRESS-TAG6c6ff5e2-b8a7-4f73-99e6-c112f7598287, org.vulgaris.behave.worker.NinthWorker], mProgress=Data {}})
```

This is incorrect for test 2). as I should see "... the last available data automatically." when WorkerActivity is RESUMED

Why doesnt the LiveData observer trigger automatically when WorkerActivity is resumed?

Comment: Do you have a sample project showcasing this issue anywhere?

Comment: @Anatolii no I dont, however I do not think thats necessary as this is such a simple mechanism and it just doesnt work as described by the code comments.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your observer is getting destroyed when you switch between activities. I can't 100% guarantee that's what's happening but based on the logs there's a pretty good chance that it does at least hit `Lifecycle.DESTROYED` state

You can use a check in your `onClick` right before you set the observer for [hasActiveObservers()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/LiveData#hasactiveobservers)

---

The observer is linked to the state of the lifecycle.

> LiveData considers an observer, which is represented by the Observer class, to be in an *active* state if its lifecycle is in the **STARTED** or **RESUMED** state.

Which means you would get updates if your activity is in that either of those states. If we look to see the conditions of each of those states they are

[RESUMED](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/Lifecycle.State.html#RESUMED)

- this state is reached *after* onResume is called.

[STARTED](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/Lifecycle.State.html#STARTED)

- For an Activity, this state is reached in two cases:
- after onStart call;
- **right before** onPause call.

Actually based on this you should see your observer get called right after the `onStart()`

However, the documentation also lists

> If the owner moves to the {@link Lifecycle.State#DESTROYED} state, the observer will
>    * automatically be removed.

which means your observer will no longer receive any updates.

[DESTROYED](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/Lifecycle.State.html#DESTROYED)

- this state is reached **right before** Activity's onDestroy call.

Now your logs don't show `onActivityDestroyed` but there seems be quite a good indication that it does at least get into the `Lifecycle.STATE == DESTROYED` based on:

```
2020-01-14 10:59:32.211 23452-23452/org.vulgaris.behave E/APPLICATION: onActivityStopped() org.vulgaris.behave.ninth.WorkerActivity@2fe5636
```

and

```
2020-01-14 10:59:32.211 23452-23452/org.vulgaris.behave E/APPLICATION: onActivitySaveInstanceState() org.vulgaris.behave.ninth.WorkerActivity@2fe5636
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The reason your observer doesn't get called is that `WorkerActivity` lifecycle doesn't move to `Lifecycle.State.DESTROYED` state in **test 2)** (just because if it does move to `Lifecycle.State.DESTROYED` then observer would be removed and it couldn't be called with `mState=SUCCEEDED` after worker finished). Consequently, observer isn't removed, it just continues to observe `LiveData` during all the time until the worker is finished.

So there is no any contradiction to documentation:

```
 * When data changes while the {@code owner} is not active, it will not receive any updates.
 * If it becomes active again, it will receive the last available data automatically.
```

Your data hasn't changed during the change of activity of obsrever, `WorkInfo` is in running state all the time.